# fts4 available in SQLite ODBC driver?

Tags: sqlite, odbc, fts3

We are using the SQLite ODBC driver from: http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

I was attempting to create an FTS table via code and was unsuccessful with the error:
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [HY000] no such module: rtree (1)

If I use System.Data.SQLite ADO.NET driver it works fine, but due to some issues I'm not going to go into, I'd like to use the ODBC driver.

Does anyone know of a way to create the FTS table via the ODBC driver?

The SQL we are currenty using is: (or something similar)

```
create virtual table if not exists SEARCH_TABLE using rtree (TABLE_ROW, COLUMN_NAME, SEARCH_VALUE);
```

Comment: Apparently, the **R-tree** module is not available in that driver. Try `FTS3` instead.

Comment: ERROR [HY000] no such module: fts3 (1) if I make that change.  So I guess FTS3 isn't available either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ODBC driver has been compiled without FTS.

You have to use System.Data.SQLite, or to recompile the ODBC driver with a changed configuration.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Thanks.